# Расположит элемент по центру из кода Android

Tags: java, android

Есть код, который убирает Textview, который расположен слева, другой расположен справа. При скрытии левого, правый должен "перемещаться" в центр. Textview находятся в айтеме, который заполняется с адаптера, это не activity. Расположены в одном RelativeLayout.

Сам код скрытия Textview

```
 if (productList.get(position).getPriceOld().toString().equals("0")){
            holder.price_txt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Comment: Многое зависит от контейнера, где ваши Textview расположены. Уточните вопрос.

Comment: Textview находятся в айтеме, который заполняется с адаптера, это не activity. Расположены в одном RelativeLayout